# SVG - Trying to figure out how to support EDGE using an svg instead of clipPath

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I used the CSS property clip path that allowed me to create the below:

https://jsfiddle.net/fLe6np59/36/

Foolishly I didn't make sure it worked on EDGE and ideally IE11 as well.

I have read online that I need to use the Clippath Element so that it works in Edge and IE11.

Which is where I get lost. I'm not sure how I can do that. I've tried wrapping my rect in a clipPath element and adding the css property to the clippath via an ID but this seems to not work.

```
clipPath {
    clip-path: polygon(52% 41%,100% 45%,100% 46%,51% 59%,0 49%,0 48%);  
}


/*Firefox*/
clip-path: url("#clipPath");
```

Would be greatful for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You might like to read this [tutorial](http://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/) about clipping in SVG and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.  Why use a CSS clip-path when you already are using an SVG?

> I've tried wrapping my rect in a clipPath element and adding the css property to the clippath via an ID

It sounds like you didn't do much research on how SVG clipPaths work.  There are numerous examples on the web on how clipPaths work. Plus you could have read the SVG specification.

But anyway, the SVG equivalent of your CSS clip path is as follows:

```html
<svg class="svg-responsive" viewBox="0 0 320 60" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClipPath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0.52, 0.41, 1, 0.45, 1, 0.46, 0.51, 0.59, 0, 0.49, 0, 0.48"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <rect class="shape" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#myClipPath)"/>
       
</svg>
```